# How to use the "adb shell pm trim-caches " command

Tags: android, shell, caching, adb

I'm trying to use the trim-caches command using various combinations, but nothing has worked.
This is one of the things I've tried :

```
adb shell pm trim-caches 222
```

I keep getting errors in the style of  "Invalid suffix:" .

The [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm) says :

> trim-caches   Trim cache files to reach the given
>   free space.

What is wrong here?

How should this command work?

Also, can it work for specific app?

Comment: your "documentation" link is wrong... here's the correct one - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1395

Comment: @AlexP. Cool. Wonder why they didn't write about it

Answer (score 3):

The `pm trim-caches` command takes the desired free space parameter in kilo/mega/gigabytes.

```
adb shell pm trim-caches 222M
```

Comment: I see. but now I get: Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: "Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE." Also, is it only globally, or can you set it to work on a specific app?

Comment: The security exception is pretty clear. And the command does not work for a specific app - it tries to delete LRU sorted list of cache files across all applications.

Comment: I see, but I called it from ADB on the PC. Why does it need a permission, and how can I grant it one? If an app has this permission on the manifest, will it work, or does it require root?